# How to calculate time for methods in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I calculate time for example of 3 methods, but it’s only the first and the last methods I need the time for. I do not need the time in the middle method. 
Ex. MethodOne takes 200 ms, MethodTwo takes 500 ms, MethodThree takes 300 ms. Total time: 1000 ms. but it should be 1000 ms – 500 ms (MethodTwo) = 500 ms.

Is there any software that can do that? Or how can I change my code so it works?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("============================");
  Console.WriteLine("        Performance         ");
  Console.WriteLine("============================\n");

  Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}", TimeTaking(MethodOne).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static TimeSpan TimeTaking(Action methodName)
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  methodName();
  stopwatch.Stop();
  return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}

static void MethodOne()
{
  Thread.Sleep(200);
  MethodTwo();
}

static void MethodTwo()
{
  // Stop TimeTaking
  Thread.Sleep(500);
  MethodThree();
}

static void MethodThree()
{ 
  // continue TimeTaking
  Thread.Sleep(300); 
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Clarify your question, please. Do you need to calculate each of your methods running time? Is methods calling "one-from-another" intended or it's your approach to calcualte?

Comment: Andy, I need to calculate each methods running time. I do not know witch methods will be called. It can be 5 methods or it can be 20 methods in different projects.

Answer (score 2):

If thread safety is not an issue you could put the `Stopwatch` outside the `TimeTaking` method. This allows you to call `Stop()` and `Start()` at the places you want (at the beginning or at the end of methods).

You could, of course, pass the `Stopwatch` around as a parameter. Or have everything return an `int`/`long` that contains the amount of ms it took to run. Both solution are quite ugly, because it either adds an extra parameter or forces `out` parameters in case you do want to return a useful value.

Comment: I have to be thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Without a seperate profiling tool, you would have to manually measure the time with a `Stopwatch` within `MethodOne` and `MethodThree`. There is no way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options here...

You use a [stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your operations to know the duration of these methods. Of course, this is repetitive code (even if you put the actual stopwatch logic code in a separate method) but may be enough for what you need.

Or, you can use [AOP with PostSharp](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/aop-method-execution-time-watcher-with-postsharp/) to do this, which avoids repetitive code if you need this behavior in all of your methods. But then you have to organize your code a bit more modular (which makes it also more testable):

```
[LogExecutionTimeAttribute]
void MethodOne()
{
   Thread.Sleep(200);     
}

void MethodTwo()
{      
   Thread.Sleep(500);
}

[LogExecutionTimeAttribute]
void MethodThree()
{ 
   Thread.Sleep(300); 
}

void StartFlow()
{
   MethodOne();
   MethodTwo();
   MethodThree();
}
```

(Not sure why you need them to be static, should be avoided)

Finally, but probably overkill for you, APM tools like AppDynamics can also do that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't using the PostSharp solution return ~1000ms for MethodOne? Because it will only record the time when the method completes, that is after MethodTwo and MethodThree.

Comment: You are right, but this encourages to write code that is less dependent of each other. Instead of methods calling each other, maybe MethodOne, MethodTwo and MethodThree could not call each other but instead another method would contain the flow of calling these methods. It would be more modular and each method can be tested independently of each other.

Comment: It think the solution will be a APM tools maybe AppDynamics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this little piece of code to do some simple measurement:

```
   public class Timer : IDisposable
   {
        private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        private readonly Action<TimeSpan> _finishedDelegate;

        private Timer(Action<TimeSpan> finishedDelegate)
        {
            if (finishedDelegate == null)
            {
                finishedDelegate = timeSpan => Debug.Print("Elapsed time: {0}", timeSpan);
            }

            _finishedDelegate = finishedDelegate;
            _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public static Timer Start(Action<TimeSpan> finishedDelegate = null)
        {
            return new Timer(finishedDelegate);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            _finishedDelegate.Invoke(_stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
   }
```

Use like:

```
using (Timer.Start())
{
   // Code to be measured here
}
```

You can provide a delegate in the Start method to control what should happen with the result. By default it outputs the time to the Debug console.